# Calling another contract's state-changing function as view function

Tags: solidity, assembly, solidity-0.6.x

In Web3 we can do `TestContract.methods.myMethod(myParam).call()` to call a state changing function without executing it. But I am wondering if this is possible in Solidity or inline-assembly? So in other words I want to call another contract's function, but not actually execute it, only get the return value or revert message.

I could add another public view function of course, but I am running out of space and my contract is getting too large. Alternatively, I know there are [several workarounds](https://blog.aragon.one/rage-against-the-ev-machine-part-1/) for contracts being too large, but nothing really ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try, but my intuition tells me that it will revert, because your non-constant function will be executed with 0 gas.

For example, suppose that your function is:

```
function myFunc(address x, uint256 y) public returns (uint256);
```

Then you can use:

```
bytes4 private constant MY_FUNC_SELECTOR = bytes4(uint256(keccak256("myFunc(address,uint256)") >> (256 - 4 * 8)));

function callMyFunc(address dest, address x, uint256 y) public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256[1] memory ret;
    bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(MY_FUNC_SELECTOR, x, y);

    assembly {
        let success := staticcall(
            gas,           // gas remaining
            dest,          // destination contract address
            add(data, 32), // input buffer (starts after the first 32 bytes in the `data` array)
            mload(data),   // input length (loaded from the first 32 bytes in the `data` array)
            ret,           // output buffer
            32             // output length
        )
        if iszero(success) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }

    return ret[0];
}
```

Note that if `myFunc` returns a tuple of 2 items, for example, then you'll need to modify the above:

```
function callMyFunc(...) public view returns (uint256, uint256) {
    uint256[2] memory ret;
    ...
    64 // output length
    ...
    return (ret[0], ret[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `staticcall` seems like what I was searching for. I've tried to run your example, but I am still having two problems. 1) The return value seems to be empty always. 2) How do I get the revert message? You can try https://pastebin.com/YgFE30Ww at Remix.

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com: Do you mean when you call this function from the on-chain (i.e., from a contract) or from the off-chain (e.g., from a web3.js-based script)?

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com: The return value is "empty always", because you removed the `if iszero(success) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }` part from the solution that I have suggested! If you left it in the code, then you would observe that the transaction always reverted, just like I had speculated at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the part, because it always reverts the transaction. (well unless the call itself reverts). But so what's the point of it if it just reverts the transaction?

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com: That's exactly what I pointed out at the very top of my answer - you cannot execute a non-constant function from a constant function because the latter would be calling the former with 0 gas.